# TYPO3 You are not allowed to access the given folder

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Im getting this error when I add/upload icons/images to:
JF_headerslider extension.
Backend_Layout.

Then i get the error "You are not allowed to access the given folder" and if i look in my folder with a FTP program, then i can see that the images is uploaded and that i have the right promissions.

Whats wrong, when i now run my live site i get a "TYPO3" Oops, an error occurred! - You are not allowed to access the given folder.

If i delete the images/icons i can run again.

Im running TYPO3 v. 6.1 + Extbase/Fluid.

[image][image]

Comment: I am got same error when i tried to use kk_downloader entension. I tried to create "processed" folder, but i did not get the issue fixed.

Comment: not "processed" but "(underscore)processed(underscore)".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ahhh

Found a solution thats working to this extension.
The TYPO3 v. 6.1.4 don't have the folder "*processed*" in the typo3temp, when added that with a FTP program to the folder, everythings works.

Can see that the missing "(underscore)processed(underscore)" fix alot of "You are not allowed to access the given folder" if the folder is missing.

Comment: That is strange ... TYPO3 should create it automatically for you.

Comment: have tried to installe 3 diffrent typo3 ver. 6.1.4 with dummy site, and all installations is without the _processed_ folder.